# Spark Streaming with large number of streams and models used for analytical processing of RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, redis, spark-streaming

We are creating a real-time stream processing system with spark streaming which uses large number (millions)  of analytic models applied to RDDs in the many different type of incoming metric data streams(more then 100000). This streams are original or transformed streams. Each RDD has to go through an analytical model for processing. Since we do not know which spark cluster node  will process which specific RDDs from different streams, we need to make ALL these models available at each Spark compute node. This will create huge overhead at each spark node. We are considering using in-memory data grids to provide these models at spark compute nodes. Is this the right approach?

Or

Should we avoid using Spark streaming all together and just use in-memory data grids like Redis(with pub/sub) to solve this problem. In that case we will stream data to specific Redis nodes which contain the specific models. of course we will have to do all binning/window etc..

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like to me like you need a combination of stream processing engine and a distributed data store. I would design the system like this.

1. The distributed datastore (Redis, Cassandra, etc.) can have the data you want to access from all the nodes.
2. Receive the data streams through a combination data ingestion system (Kafka, Flume, ZeroMQ, etc.) and process it in the stream processing system (Spark Streaming [preferably ;)], Storm, etc.).
3. In the functions that is used to process the stream records, the necessary data will have to pulled from the data store and maybe cached locally as appropriate.
4. You may also have to update the data store from spark streaming as application needs it. In which case you will also have to worry about versioning of the data that you want pull in step 3.

Hopefully that made sense. Its hard to give any more specifics of the implementation without the exactly computation model. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Tathagata. I am thinking on similar lines. The issue is point number (3) above -  What to cache at each local Spark node?. Fetching data from Redis on each data-set computation at any Spark node will be a huge overhead. Is there any way to  direct streams to specific set of KNOWN spark nodes? In that case I can cache a set of  data required at these node sets.

Comment: There is no good way to direct the streams to specific node in a Spark cluster. That is because it sort of goes against the philosophy of running deterministic tasks (like Map reduce tasks) which should be able to run on any spark node and give the same result. You will have to cache the data in your own cache. Maybe just a singleton, thread-safe hashmap, that is initialized on demand, when the first task requiring it is run.